# Web page loses responsive design after deployment

Tags: html, css, codepen

I have a webpage that has good responsive design on codepen.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/mdewyzG

The horizontal scrolling is locked, and the pictures fit the screen. I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuvxV.png

When I deploy to Surge, the pictures no longer fit the screen, and horizontal scrolling is enabled. I have checked the site in Chrome developer tools, and on several phones. On every platform, the codepen is responsive, and the deployed site is not responsive. Non responsive site here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sv1k.png

The deployed, non responsive site is here:

http://kalki.surge.sh/

I have made sure libraries like foundation and normalize are included. I ran the CSS through an auto- prefixer. I have checked for other JS and libraries and there are none.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the network tab and make sure all files are loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Comment: The surge website is accessed via http and included libraries via https, try without https: like //cdnjs.cloudfare.com/... otherwise it may be a react problem.

Comment: That makes sense. I saw the https/http issue before. I doubt it's react. Im 95% sure it's  the CSS.